# How would you convert from ASCII to Hex by character in C?

Tags: c

I basically just want to take a 8 character ASCII value `003fc000` and convert it to Hex by character.

Comment: From integer value to hex or from string'003fc000' to integer value?
  Your question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean convert it to a hex integer?

```
int num = (int)strtol("003fc000", NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Although you should use `long`, since `0x3fc000` isn't guaranteed to fit into `int`.