# Ascii hex value to ascii number

Tags: c, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you convert from ASCII to Hex by character in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700563/how-would-you-convert-from-ascii-to-hex-by-character-in-c)

I like to convert a hex value, represented in ascii code to the number represented by the hex value.

As an example:

`A5` should convert to `0xA5` (which is 165)

But `A5` is represented in `ASCII` (so something like `0x4135` I guess)

Any ideas?
Thx!

Comment: I recommend reading your friendly man page for sscanf; pay particular attention to the '%x' conversion specifier.

Comment: @jens: *scanf is a bit heavy-handed for this, but if it's part of a bigger "get data out of a string" it's perfectly sensible.

Comment: do some search first, check here [stackoverflow..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700563/how-would-you-convert-from-ascii-to-hex-by-character-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: <perl>There's more than one way to do it</perl> :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtol`.

```
long x = strtol("A5", 0, 16)
// x is now 165
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `strtol` available (I believe it is in the standard library), it should be as simple as a call to `strtol` using 16 as the base.

```
char *end
val = strtol("A5", &end, 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use sscanf():

```
sscanf("A5", "%x", &bar);
```